# Time Zone Changes CST and DST in sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What is standard time that SQL Server returns using 'datediff' function?

```
datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp)
```

Is it GMT ?

Requirement :

User-defined function to return the Timestamp in CST and DST time stamps depends on the current time (CST or day light saving).

In CST time zone i,e 'CST Time in the zone is six hours behind GMT'

```
(datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 21600)
```

During daylight saving time (DST), time in the zone is five hours behind GMT

```
(datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 18000)
```

Can anyone help me to create a user defined function for the above requirement.

Thanks & regards,
Venkat

Comment: It's usually better, once time zones are involved, to just store and process UTC values in the database and leave any zone fiddling to the parts of your system that are directly taking input from the user or presenting output to them.

Comment: Right, the problem here is we are updating the columns data from sql server end (back end). last_update_date = (datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 18000) or (datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 21600) depends on the current time zone. Always we are CST time zone. if it is day light saving we have to update with last_update_date = (datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 18000). if it is normal CST last_update_date = (datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 21600).help me to create a user defined function.

Comment: Be clear with your terms.  timestamp is not a date.  What is the data type of current_timestamp.  DATEDIFF returns an int.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: what all i need is a userdefined function like this Create function myfucntion () { if (TImezone = 'DST') select (datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 18000);  else (datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', current_timestamp) + 21600)  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you're asking, but if you want to convert UTC to CST try this function using "-6" as your UTC offset.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Name:     udfToLocalTime.sql
--Purpose:  To convert UTC to local US time accounting for DST
--Author:   Patrick Slesicki
--Date:     3/25/2014
--Notes:    Tested on SQL Server 2008R2 and later.
--          Good only for US States observing the Energy Policy Act of 2005.
--          Function doesn't apply for years prior to 2007.
--          Function assumes that the 1st day of the week is Sunday.
--Tests:        
--          SELECT dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-03-09 9:00', DEFAULT)
--          SELECT dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-03-09 10:00', DEFAULT)
--          SELECT dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-11-02 8:00', DEFAULT)
--          SELECT dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-11-02 9:00', DEFAULT)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER FUNCTION udfToLocalTime
    (
    @UtcDateTime    AS DATETIME
    ,@UtcOffset     AS INT = -8 --PST
    )
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @MyDateTime AS DATETIME
        ,@Year      AS CHAR(4)
        ,@MarTime   AS TIME
        ,@NovTime   AS TIME
        ,@Mar1      AS DATETIME
        ,@Nov1      AS DATETIME
        ,@Mar1Day   AS INT
        ,@Nov1Day   AS INT
        ,@MarDiff   AS INT
        ,@NovDiff   AS INT
        ,@DstStart  AS DATETIME
        ,@DstEnd    AS DATETIME

    SELECT
        @Year       = CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(@UtcDateTime))
        ,@MarTime   = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -@UtcOffset, '1900-01-01 02:00'))
        ,@NovTime   = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -@UtcOffset - 1, '1900-01-01 02:00'))
        ,@Mar1      = CONVERT(CHAR(16), @Year + '-03-01 ' + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @MarTime), 126)
        ,@Nov1      = CONVERT(CHAR(16), @Year + '-11-01 ' + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @NovTime), 126)
        ,@Mar1Day   = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Mar1)
        ,@Nov1Day   = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Nov1)

    --Get number of days between Mar 1 and DST start date
    IF @Mar1Day = 1 SET @MarDiff = 7
    ELSE SET @MarDiff = 15 - @Mar1Day

    --Get number of days between Nov 1 and DST end date
    IF @Nov1Day = 1 SET @NovDiff = 0
    ELSE SET @NovDiff = 8 - @Nov1Day

    --Get DST start and end dates
    SELECT 
        @DstStart   = DATEADD(DAY, @MarDiff, @Mar1)
        ,@DstEnd    = DATEADD(DAY, @NovDiff, @Nov1)

    --Change UTC offset if @UtcDateTime is in DST Range
    IF @UtcDateTime >= @DstStart AND @UtcDateTime < @DstEnd SET @UtcOffset = @UtcOffset + 1

    --Get Conversion
    SET @MyDateTime = DATEADD(HOUR, @UtcOffset, @UtcDateTime)
    RETURN @MyDateTime
END
GO
```